# HTML Background Repeats

Tags: css, image, html

I have this issue where I have a very nice background I made in photoshop and when I set as the background in HTML `<body background = "images/bg1.png">` its repeats everywhere and looks really retarded. Does anyone know how to stop it from doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you SHOULDN'T put your background on the `<body>` tag. This is deprecated since XHTML 1.0.

So to help you, use CSS and put this code:

```
body {
    background: url('images/bg1.png') no-repeat center center fixed; // or scroll
}
```

This will place your background in the center of the page and fix it or let it scroll, depending on your code and purpose.

Also, if you want, you can put `background-size: 100%;` to fill the document with the image. It will be zoomed so you will lost quality. I recommand using a high resolution image for a background.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the *no-repeat* [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background):

```
<body style="background: url('images/bg1.png') no-repeat">
```

Comment: Also deprecated since XHTML 1.0. The `style` attribute is not recommanded.